# Вовремя или во-время?

Tags: орфография, наречия, слитно-дефис

Господа, как правильно пишется это наречие? Я была уверена, что только слитно ("успеть вовремя"). Но на "Яндексе" случайно увидела [**ВО-ВРЕМЯ**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/760994#sel=) (Толковый словарь Ушакова, 1935-1940).

Это что, правда? Или устаревшая форма?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Написание наречия ВОВРЕМЯ изменилось после реформы 1956 года.

Также были введены следующие изменения в написании наречий:

А) Повидимому, попрежнему, попустому[. Сейчас — по-видимому, по-прежнему, по-пустому.

Б) Во-время, во-всю, во-свояси, на-днях. Сейчас — вовремя, вовсю, восвояси, на днях.

В настоящее время слитное написание наречия ВОВРЕМЯ связано с наличием парного существительного: прийти ВОВРЕМЯ - ВО ВРЕМЯ занятий.

Comment: Неожиданно... Интересно, какими правилами тогда руководствовались?